# print different variables at one time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Have a question about how to print several separate variable with one command in python. E.g.I have A0=5,A1=6,A2="what",A3=[1,2,3],A4=(10,100)

I can do print(A0), print(A1), print(A2), etc

But what if I have 100 such variable which starting with same character (in this case is 'A'), how to print them out with one command?

Comment: You should instead use a list, or a dictionary.

Comment: This is exactly what lists are for. Change your separate `A` variables to be a list.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't think that it is a good idea, but yes, you can do it:

```
A0 = 5
A1 = 2
A3 = 232
.
..
A999 = 25

for i in range(1000):
    line = 'print(A{0})'.format(i)
    exec(line)
```

Comment: That's indeed a very bad idea. The right solution is to use a list or a dict, not to have 999+ variables named "A0" to "ANN"

Comment: Yeah it is a bad practice, and my answer was just to prove that you can do "anything" with Python. @John feel free to accept the answer and vote up if you can.

Answer (score 0):

if you "have 100 such variables which starting with same character (in this case is 'A')" and have a need to treat them as a collection, then obviously the proper solution is to use a collection instead of distinct "A0", "A1", ... "AN" variables. Whenever you end up doing something awkward (like here), ask yourself if your data are properly structured. Chances are it's not.